# Help with animating a plot in 3D cylindrical coordinates

Tags: plotting, animation

I am trying to figure out how to animate (for different values of k) the following function in cylindrical coordinates and would appreciate some help.

$$f=r^2*k-r*cos(theta)$$

I can't seem to figure out how to plot it in a way where the gridlines are circular.

Answer (score 1):

```
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]], 
   r^2 k - r Cos[\[Theta]]}, {r, 0, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  Mesh -> Full], {k, 1, 10}]
```

https://imgur.com/LZBtKPN